# Ruby-on-Rails oauth2 works when heroku is launched from command line (heroku open), but does not work when I type in the address into the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, command-line, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have an interesting issues that I have no idea how to begin tackling it. I build a web app that uses google oauth2 that is deployed on heroku. When I launch the app from the mac command line using "heroku open" oauth works fine. When I type in the address in the URL, oauth2 gives me a:

400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

I know this error means that my google developer redirect does not match the request. However, my redirect is correct, as it works when I launch it from heroku (and not my first time using oauth).

Anyone experience this before or know how I should begin researching the solution?